# Android Studio 2.0 App icon

Tags: android

I have 1 computer with Android 1.5.1 and install Android Studio 2.0 on another computer.

I see in this new 2.0 version so have App icon so you ut in under "Image Assets" 
The app icon has got a white border around the icon, and this is simply ugly and do not look. Should this be the future of Google / Android?

So my qaestion is that:
Are there away to get it back like we have it in v1.5??
So you have app icon only and not with this white ramme around.

Answer (score 1):

Right click res/mipmap > New > Image Asset > scroll down to Shape > select None

Then you are good to go

Comment: This is the same i have do many time!
Still white border, i have try with 15 different and all is the same.
Take a look with this i have write over.
Here i have make this with different icon but they all come with border around!
https://www.dropbox.com/s/kx4mv8mpk3g0351/2016-04-15%2009.47.55.jpg?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

You have just to `right click on res`

[image]

Select `None` on the `Shape` Menu

[image]
And there you go

[image]

***You must*** `Uninstall your app` on your phone and re-build it :) therefor the app icon won't be updated

Comment: Ah ok.
Thankyou so much for this information :)
Done and working good :)

Comment: If you can valid my answer, I will be grateful

Comment: Hello,
How can i valid your answer?
I am new on Stackoverflow :)

Comment: You have just to click on the tick (√ ) near the up and down button, thanks a lot.

Comment: Thank for the info :)
I have do it now :)